# How can i set ScrollViewer able to zoom horizontal at beginning

Tags: c#, uwp, pinchzoom

My code

```
<ScrollViewer IsZoomChainingEnabled="True" IsZoomInertiaEnabled="True"  ZoomMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
<Grid>
                   <Rectangle ManipulationMode="Sytem" Name="touchRectangle"
               Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Blue"/>
                    </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I'm able to scroll horizontal when i pinch zoom but i want to scroll horizontal at start without zooming and horizontalscrollbar is hidden, any ideas how can i do this ? just like google map, i'm able to drag the view horizontal at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property to `True` or `Auto` in your xaml. Example using `True` shown below:

```
<ScrollViewer IsZoomChainingEnabled="True" IsZoomInertiaEnabled="True"  ZoomMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Comment: This make HorizontalScrollBar visible, i mean i want to hide it but i still able to scroll horizontal at start when not zooming yet on touch screen.

Comment: so let me get this straight.  `you want to be able to scroll horizontal but without the scroll bar showing.` is that correct?  If so please edit your question

Comment: edited !! please have a look on google map, we can able to drag the view horizontal at the beginning, no need to zoom